# How can I remove sections added by extensions in Explorer?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I found there's too much sections in my Explorer. Some of them were added by extensions. I can't find a setting to disable this feature.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click on the one(s) you want to remove and choose "remove from side bar"

[image]

You can also right click on "explorer" at the top of the explorer section an uncheck or check sections as desired to readd or remove sections.

[image]